# javascript - unable to get response from promise.all()

Tags: javascript, promise

I find that I cannot get the response when using `promise.all`.

The `orders` below should be an array

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function (orders) {
  console.log(orders); // nothing logged
});
```

Full code

```
let promises = markets.map(async (mkt) => {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    return functionA(paramA)
      .then(resA => {
        return res.functionB()
          .then((resB) => {
            if (resB.length > 0) {
              return functionC()
                .then(resC => {
                  console.log(resC); // successfully logged
                  return resC;
                });
            }
          });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function (orders) {
  console.log(orders); // nothing logged
});
```

How can I fix?

**Update 1**
I update the code based on the comment.
The `orders` is now returning

```
(54) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, Array(1), undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, Array(1), undefined, Array(1), undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

How can I make the promise returns without `undefined`?

```
const promises = markets.map(async mkt => {
  const resA = await functionA(paramA);
  const resB = await res.functionB();
  if (resB.length > 0) {
    const resC = await functionC()
    console.log(resC); // successfully logged
    return resC;
  }
});
Promise.all(promises).then(orders => {
  console.log(orders); // nothing logged
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: why are you making a prose (not using its resolve) when you have a promise from the functionA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you never `resolve()` or `reject()` the `new Promise`s you're creating. Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) and [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

This code can be greatly simplified by consequent usage of `async`/`await` instead of `.then()`:

```
const promises = markets.map(async mkt => {
  const resA = await functionA(paramA);
  const resB = await res.functionB();
  if (resB.length > 0) {
    const resC = await functionC()
    console.log(resC); // successfully logged
    return resC;
  }
});
Promise.all(promises).then(orders => {
  console.log(orders); // nothing logged
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: please check my update above

Comment: @CCCC You're getting the `undefined` values from the `else` cases where the asynchronous function doesn't return anything. Just filter them out before logging the results.

Answer (score 2):

- The Promise constructor ignores any value returned from its callback
- You aren't calling `resolve` anywhere
- You don't need to construct a Promise when you're calling a function that already gives you a Promise

```
const promises = markets.map((mkt) => {
    return functionA(paramA)
        .then(resA => res.functionB())
        .then((resB) => {
            if (resB.length > 0) {
                return functionC()
                    .then(resC => {
                        console.log(resC); // successfully logged
                        return resC;
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(handleError);
});
```

A better approach would be to utilize `await` to make the code flat and easy to read.

```
const promises = markets.map(async (mkt) => {
    try {
        const resA = await functionA(paramA);
        const resB = await res.functionB();

        if (resB.length > 0) {
            const resC = await functionC()
            return resC;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // handle errors
    }
});
```

You also might consider handling errors in the `Promise.all`, not in the mapper.

If you want to include only items for which `functionC` is called, filter out the empty values afterwards.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function (orders) {
  const filtered = orders.filter(Boolean);
  console.log(filtered);
});
```

Comment: please check my update above